# Why does rotated (R) shapes, that I copy and duplicate (Cmd+D) around a circle, get disordered?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, alignment

**Hey, guys,** i got this problem and it's really bothering me, when I make a shape, like a single rectangle and i want to rotate/duplicate it all 360º around a circle shape, **the ones that are at the central parts (0º, 90º, 180º and 270º) always move a bit.**

[image: Central shapes (0º, 90º, 180º and 270º) always move a bit]

But it isn't all, when I **MOVE** (or expand something, for example) my groups **ALL together,** no exclusions, sometimes (almost every time) those **same shapes move different** than the other objects :/

[image: Examples]

WHY!? (Although it isn't such a big deal at simple sight, but it is when you try other stuff) Please help me if you know any tip or at least answer: why does this happen? :/

I would like to thank you in advance.

---

So, this are my "View" settings.

[image: View Settings]

Then, i'll show you how i duplicate this shapes:

1. I draw my circle and put a pair of guides to intersect at center. (And just look! I don't know why I can't align precisely sometimes, it makes me go mad.)
   [image: circle]
2. Then i make my shape guiding from the center of the circle, like this. (And it won't go aligned from the center of the shape to the center of the circle).
   [image: Center shape]
3. Next step, I press (R) to bring out Rotate tool, then press alt/option key and click in the center of my circle to pop up this window, I edit the options for example as this, check preview option and hit Copy instead of OK.
   [image: rotate tool]
4. This is what I have. Then...
   [image: copied 2nd shape]
5. ...I just press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and duplicate al the shapes till i get the complete circle.
   From here you already are able to see my problem, first and last shapes are not aligned.
   [image: 1of2_duplicated]
   [image: 2of2_duplicated]

This is how they look selected and I made a group of this.
[image: selected]

6. For example, I make that group a 'compound path', then copy/move (alt>click+move) it to the right and it makes more evident the issue if you look well.
   [image: move right]
7. Another example is that this last object moved to the right, I color it gray for you to distinguish the "original" from these other copies scaled from center (alt key)... AND THIS IS WHAT I GOT JUST FOR SCALING IT!! ARGH!
   Look at this, the bigger one has those shapes I mentioned before Thin, the original has them out of alignment and finally the smaller has those same shapes thicker.

WTH!?
[image: example]

Comment: Good question, but one thing you might add is defining exactly how you're duplicating the rectangles. Thanks for contributing and welcome to GraphicDesign!

Comment: Align to pixel grid on or off?

Comment: You're right, Zach, and thank you very much. 
Scott, "align to pixel grid" is off.

I'll post an "answer" with some images. The only thing is that my Ai is in Spanish, hope you understand my translation.